# Rate limiting AWS CloudWatch logs ingestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using [awslogs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/) logging driver for my docker-compose stack. On Friday night, the EC2 instance ran out of space, and as such a NodeJS server dependent on a Redis server started throwing error: `BRPOPLPUSH ReplyError: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk.`, as Redis was not able to write to disk anymore. While this was remedied when I made some space on the server, the `awslogs` driver logged the repeated error over a period of 1 and half days to the order of 250+ GB  costing me ~$150 in [data ingestion costs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/).

While this is resolved for now, is there is a way to rate-limit the AWS CloudWatch logs ingestion, either using the `awslogs` driver or using the [AWS CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)? I use the CloudWatch agent to "watch" files for changes in many projects and this scares me about such an eventuality in any of them.

The only solution I saw so far, is SegmentIO's [rate-limiting-proxy](https://github.com/segmentio/rate-limiting-log-proxy) described [here](https://segment.com/blog/bob-loblaws-log-blog/). But the project is not maintained anymore and seems a bit complicated without documentation for composing pieces.

Comment: I can't think of any simple solution short of writing your own logging driver that folds duplicate log messages.  Why not take a step back though - seems to me the real issue here is that you were not notified until 1.5 days later. Maybe consider configuring some CW alerts on errors in logs?

Comment: It would also be a good idea, if this is a production server, to set up [disk space and memory monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html). You can also set alarms on [CloudWatch Logs ingest metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatch-Logs-Monitoring-CloudWatch-Metrics.html), to alert somebody that something is wrong.

Comment: jingx and Parsifal: getting alerted from CW is a must-have, but seems more like a curative solution than a preventative one. There should be an in-between service that validates the logs and only sends good and necessary logs at a reasonable rate.